# ¿Se puede crear una base de sql server desde php?

Tags: php, sql-server

Mi pregunta es si se puede crear una base de datos de SQL Server desde PHP, ¿cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia y no se ajusta bien al formato y contenido del sitio. Deberías editarla para añadir más información: ¿qué has intentado/investigado sobre el tema? ¿con qué problemas te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede.

Establece una conexión a la base de datos `master`, que siempre existe, y sobre ella puedes lanzar una [sentencia de creación de base de datos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql), que puede ser tan simple como:

```sql
create database MiBaseDeDatos;
```

En este caso, no debe existir previamente una base de datos con el nombre `MiBaseDeDatos`.

Un ejemplo rápido:

```php
<?php
  $serverName = "MiPC\\SQLExpress"; 
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"master", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"contrasenia del sa");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
  if ($conn) {
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "create database MiBaseDeDatos");
    if( $result === false ) {
      echo "No se pudo crear la base de datos.<br />";
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    } else {
      echo "Conexión establecida y base de datos creada.<br />";
    }
  } else {
    echo "No se pudo establecer la conexión.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
?>
```